# Highcharts - remove points from series

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to remove certain points from a series?
I'm looking for some way to draw a chart with a fixed back period,
something like: the last 1 hour.

I know how to add points using dynamic update:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

But in my case the time interval between points is not constant,
so I can't just use the shift option of [addPoint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint%28%29).

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the same, you can use the same logic as in addPoint, see: http://jsfiddle.net/JKCLx/1/

However, why can't you just use `shift` argument in `addPoint()`?

Comment: Thanks, Your solution works, but I don't understand it, so could you please clarify a bit? the shift argument means that for every point I add I remove another one, but if the time interval between the points in not constant this logic isn't correct. So what I really need is a removePoint() function that does not cause the series to be fully redrawn.

Comment: What do you mean by not fully redraw? You can or redraw or not, also you can't just cut part of a chart when removing point. Yes, shift works in that way, so when new point added remove the last one. How about adding one more point to the chart, which will be outside the plotting area, and removing that point when new arrives? Or there can be the same number as visible points, so irregular interval won't be the problem, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a partial answer to my own question:

I can iterate over the series datapoints like this:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.data

and then call [point.Remove](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.remove%28%29).

The problem with this solution is that it does not draw monitor style like in the example,
but rather it redrwas the entire chart on each change.

http://jsfiddle.net/JKCLx/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, false);                           
                           // series.data[0].remove(false);
                            series.data[0].remove(true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: In the point remove() you can se redraw as false, and set true only on last remove(). Then animation / redraw will be call single time.

Comment: yes , but this still doesn't give the same animation as shift, take a look at the attached jsfiddle. The points are all redrawn.